# perl: use string as piece of code

Tags: perl, string

I would like to use a string (e.g. read from a file) as a piece of code in my perl program. For example, I read a string (e.g. `$str="1..100,171,398..1000"`) then I would like to print all the numbers in the range represented by the string.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Your text made it look like you want to read in a string and execute it as a Perl statement, but your example seems like a case where you want to parse a string as input to a bit of code. Which is it?

Comment: I want to read in a string and execute it as a Perl statement. For example, I can achieve my goal using `for $i (1..100,171,398..1000) {print "$i "}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that specific case, see [How can I expand a string like "1..15,16" into a list of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016766/how-can-i-expand-a-string-like-1-15-16-into-a-list-of-numbers)

In general, `eval` is used to execute code in a string.  If you have an entire file of code to execute, use `do`.  But make sure that the file/string are secure before considering this.
If in fact the "code" is restricted to something like your example, do *not* use eval or do.

Update: turns out Number::Range is dog slow for large ranges; for your case you are far better off using - instead of .. in your ranges and using Set::IntSpan.  You ask about efficiency: using an array will consume a few megabytes of memory, but that isn't all that bad.  Set::IntSpan does provide iteration methods you could use instead of just generating the array, but I probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks for Number::Range! Adding another question: my ranges are quite large (~500k numbers, usually in two blocks only, i.e. something like 1..20000,,700000..1000000). What is the most efficient way to simply print them out to a file? Creating an actual array (as in the example) does not seem like a great idea, or does it?

Answer (score 1):

[Number::Range](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number::Range) uses the `..` syntax that you have, but it doesn't have an iterator.  [Set::IntSpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set::IntSpan) uses `-` instead of `..`, but it *does* have an iterator, which makes printing out the set without creating a giant array easy.

```
use Set::IntSpan;

my $str = "1..100,171,398..1000";
$str =~ s/\.\./-/g;
my $set = Set::IntSpan->new($str);

for (my $i = $set->first; defined $i; $i = $set->next) {
  print "$i\n"; # Or however you'd like to format it
}
```

Internally, Set::IntSpan stores the ranges, so this should be fairly memory-efficient.  You could also use the `spans` method to get the parsed ranges.  This would require you to write a bit more code, but would mean you don't have to do a method call for each number in the range.  Method calls in Perl are a bit slow, but I wouldn't worry about it unless the above code takes too long to run.

Comment: Thank you cjm. An nice and elegant solution, but it doesn't work for me since Set::IntSpan requires the ranges to be sorted, while mine aren't necessarily (for a reason).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to execute code in a variable.  Although the interpolation can be fun.

`eval "for ($str) { print \"\$_\n\";}"`