# perl - convert string of numeric values/ranges to actual values

Tags: perl, string-conversion, numeric-ranges

I'd like to convert a sting of the form `1,2,25-27,4,8,14,7-10` into a list of the actual values: `1,2,4,7,8,9,10,14,25,26,27`.

I've searched and found nothing that does this sort of expansion. Anyone aware of way to do this easily?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1016766/725418

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $s = "1,2,25-27,4,8,14,7-10";
my %seen;
my @arr =
  sort { $a <=> $b }
  grep { !$seen{$_}++ }
  map { 
    my @r = split /-/; 
    @r>1 ? ($r[0] .. $r[1]) : @r;
  }
  split /,/, $s;

print "@arr\n";
```

output

```
1 2 4 7 8 9 10 14 25 26 27
```

Comment: I'll write explanation if you need it

Comment: The perl is strong with this one! That's elegant and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you very much. While I could not have written that on my own, I can follow what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this quickly is by using the string version of **eval**. But you have to keep in mind that the use of eval have some security implication so you better sanitize any string before passing it to eval.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "1,2,25-27,4,8,14,7-10";

$string =~ s/-/../g;

my @list = sort {$a <=> $b} keys { map {$_, 1} eval $string };

print "@list\n";  

#output
1 2 4 7 8 9 10 14 25 26 27
```